# Library not found for -lAFNetworking with Seafile-iOS SDK

Tags: swift, objective-c, seafile-server

I'm trying to implement Seafile-iOS-SDK in a Swift app : https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-iOS but I can't pass this Library not found for -lAFNetworking when I try to compile my project.
I already tried to pod update, reinstall pods, clean Derived Data ... I'm openning xcworkspace.
I'm lost with this and ask for your help.